# How to do auto-reloading of jinja 2 data in Flask without refreshing page?

Tags: python, jquery, html, python-3.x, jinja2

I'm trying to load the data into json2 template as soon as there is new data available without refreshing the page but I'm unable to do that, this is what I tried till now main Function

```
@app.route("/")
def index1():
return render_template("index.html",gamest=get_games())
```

endpoint on the server that returns info.

```
@app.route("/sys_info.json")
def index():
     return get_games()
```

jinja 2 scripts:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<div id="content">{{ index }}</div> {# this is the original system_info passed in from the root view #}

<script>
setInterval(function(){ // load the data from your endpoint into the div
    $("#content").load("/sys_info.json")
},1000)
</script>

<div class="list-group">
            {% for  game in gamest %}
            <a class="score-size text-xs-center nounderline list-group-item list-group-item-action" >
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-4">
                     {% if game["Batting_team_img"] %}
                     <img class="team-logo" src="/static/{{ game["Batting_team_img"] }}">
                     {% endif %}
                     {{ game["Batting team"] }}  {{ game["runs10"] }}
                     </b>
                     <br>
                     {{ game["wickets10"] }}
                  </div>
```

I can see only change in the value in terminal but I can't see any changes in webpage data remains static, how can I fix this so data are changed dynamically in the website without refreshing page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is requested but the html is not refreshed by the js script. You have to add the logic for the browser to load the data in the html. For example:

```
setInterval(function() {
    // load the data from your endpoint into the div
    $.getJSON("/sys_info.json", function (data) {
       $.each(data, function (_, element) {
         $('.list-group').append('<div>' + elment['Batting team'] + '</div>);
       });
    })
},1000)
```

You need the client browser to do the same you do on the server with jijna.

Comment: thank you @mberacochea for answering, can you help me to understand javascript code?

Comment: I can't check this out since no live data available right now

Comment: I would recommend you to read some tutorial. The MDN has good documentation, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX

Comment: This is not working for me, setInterval(function() {
    // load the data from your endpoint into the div
    $("#content").load("/sys_info.json").then(function (data) {
       $.each(data, function (_, element) {
         $('.list-group').append('<div>' + elment["runs10"] + '</div>');
       });
    })
},1000) I can't see any changes in value

Comment: Is there an error on the console?. Did you debug the code?

Comment: Check the updated answer, .load is used to load data directly into the DOM. Use .getJSON instead. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/.
The problem with the answer was that .load doesn't return a promise, that is what .then is for.

Comment: still,  getting console error https://imgur.com/1EIhLao, can't check the change in data since no live data available, anything wrong?

Comment: check the edited code and please read the documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/